# Input blocks hotkeys

Tags: reactjs, hotkeys

Used `hotkey.js` to bind the hotkeys refer the below snippet. The input block my hotkey because of the focus. Now I need to enable my hotkey whether the input is focused or not.

```
import React from 'react'
import hotkeys from 'hotkeys-js'

export default function Example (props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    hotkeys('Enter', event => {
      event.preventDefault()

      return props.handleSubmit()
    })

    return () => {
      hotkeys.unbind('Enter')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' autofocus />
      <button onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found 3 errors here,

1. By default hotkeys are disabled for INPUT SELECT TEXTAREA elements. Need to add code block to enable hotkeys.
2. You dont import `useEffect`.
3. I don't think return is needed on `hotKeys` callback.

Add this code block to enable hotkeys in blocked elements

```
 hotkeys.filter = function(event){
  var tagName = (event.target || event.srcElement).tagName;
  hotkeys.setScope(/^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|SELECT)$/.test(tagName) ? 'input' : 'other');
  return true;
}
```

[Check the working fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2mxyzq)

This is the working fiddle example code.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import hotkeys from 'hotkeys-js'

export default function Hello (props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    hotkeys.filter = function(event){
      var tagName = (event.target || event.srcElement).tagName;
      hotkeys.setScope(/^(INPUT|TEXTAREA|SELECT)$/.test(tagName) ? 
      'input' : 'other');
      return true;
    }
    hotkeys('Enter', event => {
      event.stopPropagation()
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log('Hotkey Pressed')
      props.handleSubmit(); // this should do the job.
    })

    return () => {
      hotkeys.unbind('Enter')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' autoFocus />
      <button onClick={props.handleSubmit}
      >Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```